# Group data by the change of grouping column value in order

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, gaps-and-islands

With the following data

```
create table #ph (product int, [date] date, price int)
insert into #ph select 1, '20120101', 1
insert into #ph select 1, '20120102', 1
insert into #ph select 1, '20120103', 1
insert into #ph select 1, '20120104', 1
insert into #ph select 1, '20120105', 2
insert into #ph select 1, '20120106', 2
insert into #ph select 1, '20120107', 2
insert into #ph select 1, '20120108', 2
insert into #ph select 1, '20120109', 1
insert into #ph select 1, '20120110', 1
insert into #ph select 1, '20120111', 1
insert into #ph select 1, '20120112', 1
```

I would like to produce the following output:

```
product | date_from | date_to  | price
  1     | 20120101  | 20120105 |   1
  1     | 20120105  | 20120109 |   2
  1     | 20120109  | 20120112 |   1
```

If I group by price and show the max and min date then I will get the following which is not what I want (see the over lapping of dates).

```
product | date_from | date_to  | price
  1     | 20120101  | 20120112 |   1
  1     | 20120105  | 20120108 |   2
```

So essentially what I'm looking to do is group by the step change in data based on group columns product and price.

What is the cleanest way to achieve this?

Comment: This is an instance of what's known as the 'Gaps and Islands' problem, fyi.

Comment: @AakashM will take a look at that, I tried searching but didn't have such a clear definition for the problem. Thanks

Comment: np. Having a 'numbers table' (in this case, a 'dates table') will help immensely.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

There's a (more or less) known technique of solving this kind of problem, involving two [`ROW_NUMBER()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) calls, like this:

```
WITH marked AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    grp = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY product        ORDER BY date)
        - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY product, price ORDER BY date)
  FROM #ph
)
SELECT
  product,
  date_from = MIN(date),
  date_to   = MAX(date),
  price
FROM marked
GROUP BY
  product,
  price,
  grp
ORDER BY
  product,
  MIN(date)
```

Output:

```
product  date_from   date_to        price 
-------  ----------  -------------  ----- 
1        2012-01-01  2012-01-04     1     
1        2012-01-05  2012-01-08     2     
1        2012-01-09  2012-01-12     1
```

Comment: Thanks, I've just taken a look at what I ended up implementing and it's the same but I did it in two different CTEs, it didn't occur to me to use subtraction in one. Thanks.

Comment: @andriy , is there any other more optimal way to do so?

Comment: @eshirvana: There are other options, yes, but it's hard to know whether they would be more optimal for you. Off the top of my head, there's a method involving tagging rows with 1s and 0s using CASE + LAG() and then applying SUM() OVER to that column. Browsing the `gaps-and-islands` tag for ready solutions either [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gaps-and-islands) or [over at DBA.SE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gaps-and-islands) might help. You could also try submitting your own question, of course.

Answer (score 2):

I'm new to this forum so hope my contribution is helpful.

If you really don't want to use a CTE (although I think thats probably the best approach) you can get a solution using set based code. You will need to test the performance of this code!.

I have added in an extra temp table so that I can use a unique identifier for each record but I suspect you will already have this column in you source table. So heres the temp table.

```
    If Exists (SELECT Name FROM tempdb.sys.tables WHERE name LIKE '#phwithId%')
        DROP TABLE #phwithId    

    CREATE TABLE #phwithId
    (
        SaleId INT
        , ProductID INT
        , Price Money
        , SaleDate Date 
    )
    INSERT INTO #phwithId SELECT row_number() over(partition by product order by [date] asc) as SalesId, Product, Price, Date FROM ph
```

Now the main body of the Select statement

```
    SELECT 
        productId 
        , date_from
        , date_to
        , Price
    FROM
        (   
            SELECT 
                dfr.ProductId
                , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ProductId ORDER BY ChangeDate) AS rowno1          
                , ChangeDate AS date_from
                , dfr.Price
            FROM
                (       
                    SELECT
                        sl1.ProductId AS ProductId
                        , sl1.SaleDate AS ChangeDate
                        , sl1.price
                    FROM
                        #phwithId sl1
                    LEFT JOIN
                        #phwithId sl2
                        ON sl1.SaleId = sl2.SaleId + 1
                    WHERE
                        sl1.Price <> sl2.Price OR sl2.Price IS NULL
                ) dfr
        ) da1
    LEFT JOIN
        (   
            SELECT 
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ProductId ORDER BY ChangeDate) AS rowno2
                , ChangeDate AS date_to     
            FROM
                (   
                    SELECT 
                        sl1.ProductId
                        , sl1.SaleDate AS ChangeDate
                    FROM
                        #phwithId sl1
                    LEFT JOIN
                        #phwithId sl3
                        ON sl1.SaleId = sl3.SaleId - 1  
                    WHERE
                        sl1.Price <> sl3.Price OR sl3.Price IS NULL         
                ) dto

        ) da2 
        ON da1.rowno1 = da2.rowno2
```

By binding the data source offset by 1 record (+or-) we can identify when the price buckets change and then its just a matter of getting the start and end dates for the buckets back into a single record.

All a bit fiddly and I'm not sure its going to give better performance but I enjoyed the challenge.

Answer (score 2):

```
WITH marked AS (
  SELECT
    *,
  case
   when (lag(price,1,'') over (partition by product order by date_from)) = price
   then 0 else 1
  end is_price_change
  FROM #ph
),
marked_as_group AS
( SELECT m.*,
       SUM(is_price_change) over (PARTITION BY product order by date_from ROWS 
      BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS price_change_group
  FROM marked m
),
SELECT
  product,
  date_from = MIN(date_from),
  date_to   = MAX(date_to),
  price = MIN(price)
FROM marked_as_group 
GROUP BY
  product,
  price_change_group
ORDER BY
  product,
  date_to
```

Comment: I post this solution because I have the similar problem but I have some bugs when applied Andriy M's solution.

Answer (score 0):

One solution I have come up with which is relatively "clean" is:

```
;with cte_sort (product, [date], price, [row])
as
    (select product, [date], price, row_number() over(partition by product order by [date] asc) as row
     from #ph)

select a.product, a.[date] as date_from, c.[date] as date_to, a.price 
from cte_sort a
left outer join cte_sort b on a.product = b.product and (a.row+1) = b.row and a.price = b.price
outer apply (select top 1 [date] from cte_sort z where z.product = a.product and z.row > a.row order by z.row) c
where b.row is null
order by a.[date]
```

I used a CTE with `row_number` because you then don't need to worry about whether any dates are missing if you use functions like `dateadd`.  You obviously only need the outer apply if you want to have the date_to column (which I do).

This solution does solve my problem, I am however having a slight issue getting it to perform as quickly as I'd like on my table of 5 million rows.

Answer (score -1):

```
Create function [dbo].[AF_TableColumns](@table_name nvarchar(55))
returns nvarchar(4000) as
begin
declare @str nvarchar(4000)
    select @str = cast(rtrim(ltrim(column_name)) as nvarchar(500)) + coalesce('         ' + @str , '            ') 
    from information_schema.columns
    where table_name = @table_name
    group by table_name, column_name, ordinal_position 
    order by ordinal_position DESC
return @str
end

--select dbo.AF_TableColumns('YourTable') Select * from YourTable
```