# Return first and last date of contiguous blocks in intermittent date series

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, gaps-and-islands

I'm working with SQL Server 2008 R2 and have the following table.

```
CREATE TABLE room
(id int, 
 dt date, 
 course char(1), 
 constraint pk_roomtime primary key (id, dt)
);

INSERT INTO room (id, dt, course) values
(1, '20140412', 'A'),
(1, '20140414', 'A'),
(1, '20140415', 'A'),
(1, '20140416', 'B'),
(1, '20140417', 'A'),
(1, '20140421', 'A'),
(1, '20140422', 'B'),
(1, '20140423', 'B');
```

I have to find the first and last date for each block of courses in a room without regard to the gaps between dates. My result for room 1 should look like this:

```
A    20140412    20140415
B    20140416    20140416
A    20140417    20140421
B    20140422    20140423
```

I tried using a join to a calendar table but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: The first three dates of course A ( 12 / 14 / 15 ) are not consecutive. So what's the rule the two follwowing dates of course A ( 17 / 21 ) are not part of the first result set of course A?

Comment: Truth be told, in 2008 it's by far the easiest to use a cursor. If you can upgrade to 2012, it could be very ellegantly solved with improved window functions.

Comment: @dean - How would you achieve a result like the one mentioned with window functions? I don't see any difference between the first three datasets and the 5th and 6th to achieve a different result - except the fact that there is an interruption of type B. Is this the rule to separate the sets?

Comment: @Nico Check my answer below for the 2012 solution. I couldn't paste it here in comments.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Group data by the change of grouping column value in order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10110026/group-data-by-the-change-of-grouping-column-value-in-order)

Comment: @Andriy M - You are correct. Your answer in that thread is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sake of completeness, and to answer a question raised in @Nico comment, here's the 2012 solution (I'm aware the OP uses 2008r2):

```
with x as (
    select *,
    lag(dt) over(order by dt) as lag_dt,
    lag(course) over(order by dt) as lag_course
    from room
),
y as (
    select *,
    sum(case when course<>lag_course then 1 else 0 end) over(order by dt) as grp
    from x
)
select min(course), min(dt), max(dt)
from y
group by grp
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the resultset you asked for, but I think the result itself matches your idea:

```
with "cte" as 
(
select 
    rn = row_number() over ( order by dt )
    , * 
from room
)
,"preprocessed" as 
(
select
    "current"."course"
    , startDate = case when "predecessor"."id" is null then "current"."dt" else null end
    , endDate = case when "successor"."id" is null then "current"."dt" else null end
    , "current"."dt"
from 
    "cte" as "current"
    left join "cte" as predecessor
        on 1 = 1
        and "current"."id" = predecessor."id"
        and "current"."course" = predecessor."course"
        and "current"."rn" -1 = predecessor."rn"

    left join "cte" as successor
        on 1 = 1
        and "current"."id" = successor."id"
        and "current"."course" = successor."course"
        and "current"."rn" +1 = successor."rn"
), "pvt" as
(
select
    "course"
    , "dt"
    , "type"
from
    ( select "course", "startDate", "endDate"  from "preprocessed" ) as data
     unpivot ( "dt" for "type" in ( "startDate", "endDate")) as pvt
)
select * from 
    "pvt"
```

[See SQL-Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9f435/2/0)