# SQL Server - group by with row number - Gaps and Islands

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, row-number

I have a table with data like this

```
+-------------+--------------+------------+----------------+
| CustomerSID | StartDateSID | EndDateSID | MarketingOptIn |
+-------------+--------------+------------+----------------+
|       12345 |     20101019 |   20131016 | Y              |
|       12345 |     20131017 |   20140413 | Y              |
|       12345 |     20140414 |   20140817 | N              |
|       12345 |     20140818 |   20141228 | N              |
|       12345 |     20141229 |   20150125 | Y              |
|       12345 |     20150126 |          0 | Y              |
+-------------+--------------+------------+----------------+
```

I need to create a view on top of this table to have data formatted in the below format for the Flag, basically the duration for which the Flag was Y or N.
(EndDateSID - 0 is currently active, so today's date)

```
+-------------+--------------+------------+----------------+
| CustomerSID | StartDateSID | EndDateSID | MarketingOptIn |
+-------------+--------------+------------+----------------+
|       12345 |     20101019 |   20140413 | Y              |
|       12345 |     20140414 |   20141228 | N              |
|       12345 |     20141229 |   20150825 | Y              |
+-------------+--------------+------------+----------------+
```

Most customers only have a change in their Flag once, hence below query works:

```
SELECT 
CH1.CustomerSID
,MIN(CH1.StartDateSID) StartDate
,MAX(ISNULL(NULLIF(CH1.EndDateSID,0),CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 112)))) EndDate
,CH1.MarketingOptIn 
FROM DWH.DimCustomerHistory CH1
GROUP BY CH1.CustomerSID, CH1.MarketingOptIn
ORDER BY CH1.CustomerSID, CH1.MarketingOptIn
```

How can I achieve the intended output for customers like the one above, having changes in the flag more than once?

Comment: Hello Rohit welcome to StackOverflow, next time try to provide a 
[**SqlFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5368b/6) so we can understand the problem better and give you an answer 
much faster – Also please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  Also read
[**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Group data by the change of grouping column value in order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10110026/group-data-by-the-change-of-grouping-column-value-in-order)

Comment: Hi @JuanCarlosOropeza, thank you for the suggestions, I'll follow them next time onwards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a [gaps and islands problem](https://manning-content.s3.amazonaws.com/download/3/e589652-7171-4310-a714-e84dd0f14090/SampleChapter5.pdf). You need to use `ROW_NUMBER()` to identify your gaps, so the start stage would be:

```
SELECT  CustomerSID,
        StartDateSID,
        EndDateSID,
        MarketingOptIn,
        TotalRowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CustomerSID ORDER BY StartDateSID),
        RowNumInGroup = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CustomerSID, MarketingOptIn ORDER BY StartDateSID),
        GroupID = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CustomerSID ORDER BY StartDateSID) -   
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CustomerSID, MarketingOptIn ORDER BY StartDateSID)
FROM    dbo.YourTable;
```

Output:

```
CustomerSID StartDateSID    EndDateSID  MarketingOptIn  TotalRowNum RowNumInGroup   GroupID
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
12345       20101019        20131016    Y               1           1               0
12345       20131017        20140413    Y               2           2               0
12345       20140414        20140817    N               3           1               2
12345       20140818        20141228    N               4           2               2
12345       20141229        20150125    Y               5           3               2
12345       20150126        0           Y               6           4               2
```

The key here is that by taking the row number of each row, and also the row number of each row withing the group, you can get a unique identifier (GroupID + MarketingOptIn) which identifies each of your islands. Then it is just a case of grouping by this identifier when doing your aggregates:

**FULL WORKING EXAMPLE**

```
DECLARE @T TABLE 
(   
    CustomerSID INT,
    StartDateSID INT,
    EndDateSID INT,
    MarketingOptIn CHAR(1)
)
INSERT @T 
VALUES
    (12345, 20101019, 20131016, 'Y'),
    (12345, 20131017, 20140413, 'Y'),
    (12345, 20140414, 20140817, 'N'),
    (12345, 20140818, 20141228, 'N'),
    (12345, 20141229, 20150125, 'Y'),
    (12345, 20150126, 0, 'Y');


WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  CustomerSID,
            StartDateSID,
            EndDateSID,
            MarketingOptIn,
            GroupID = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CustomerSID ORDER BY StartDateSID) -   
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CustomerSID, MarketingOptIn ORDER BY StartDateSID)
    FROM    @T
)
SELECT  CustomerSID, 
        StartDateSID = MIN(StartDateSID),
        EndDateSID = CASE WHEN MIN(EndDateSID) = 0 THEN CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112)) ELSE MAX(EndDateSID) END,
        MarketingOptIn
FROM    CTE
GROUP BY CustomerSID, MarketingOptIn, GroupID
ORDER BY CustomerSID, StartDateSID;
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT CustomerSID,
       MIN(StartDateSID) AS StartDate,
       MAX(ISNULL(NULLIF(EndDateSID,0),
           CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 112)))) AS EndDate,
       MarketingOptIn
FROM (       
  SELECT CustomerSID, StartDateSID, EndDateSID, MarketingOptIn,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY StartDateSID) - 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerSID, MarketingOptIn 
                            ORDER BY StartDateSID) AS grp     
  FROM DimCustomerHistory ) AS t
GROUP BY CustomerSID, MarketingOptIn, grp
ORDER BY StartDate
```

Calculated field `grp` serves to identify *consecutive* records having the same `MarketingOptIn` value.

Utilizing this field in an outer query, you can easily `GROUP BY` and apply `MIN` and `MAX` aggregate functions in a way similar to your original query.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d78a7/3)